# CSS for Bootstrap 4 modal to slide in from bottom

Tags: css, transform, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

This is how it was done in **Bootstrap 3**:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
}
```

Or something like this would have worked as well:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

The magic obviously happened in the modal classes with the transform property. But this does not work in **Bootstrap 4**. I am specifically using [Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/). What changes do I need to make to achieve the same effect?

Demo url - https://jsfiddle.net/qww47vfn/

Comment: I've got a possible solution, but I'd like to see your modal in action before I can post it as an answer. Do you have a live example?

Comment: Demo url - https://jsfiddle.net/qww47vfn/

Answer (score 3):

Found it, apply the following CSS:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,25%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,25%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,25%);
    transform: translate(0,25%);
}
```

I've inverted the transform origin, instead of -25%, it's now 25% (effectively making it fade in from below). Adjust the amount to adjust the initial fade in position.

#### What changed?

Instead of `translate3d` the property `translate` is now being used, so changing the original values won't matter since the model listens to the new properties now.

#### Side note:

This doesn't work when you implement it as a new rule for some reason, I don't have a local version of bootstrap, but changing it inside the DevTools solved it for me. I suppose you need to overwrite the initial code to change it.

Comment: I saw this too and attempted the overwrite which led to my confusion. Bootstrap 4 has a long way to go I think.